# Missing Column Assignment for 'featurename'

Tags: presto

I am trying to write a CASE statement in which I need to run the subquery to check whether the record is available in access table. If the person has access then score should anything between 0 to 100 which is taken care by coalesce and if not then the value should be NULL. But the query is failing with the error saying, Missing column Assignment for 'id'.

My query:

```
SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM hive_dsn.db.access AS aa WHERE ub.id=aa.id) 
                 THEN COALESCE(ub.score*100,0)
            ELSE 
                 NULL
        END AS UNUSED
FROM hive_dsn.db.unused_output AS ub;
```

Basically, I did not understand the error statement. What this error is saying and how can I resolve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: MySQL, SQL or Hive. Which one is it?

Comment: Presto (Results are persisted to SQL Server and Hive)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the where condition is checking on columns rather than values without any JOIN. 
I rewrote query like follows:

```
SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ub.personid FROM hive_dsn.db.access AS aa 
                              JOIN hive_dsn.db.unused_output AS ub  ON ub.id=aa.id) 
                    THEN COALESCE(ub.score*100,0)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS UNUSED
from hive_dsn.db.unusedoutput AS ub;
```

This JOIN condition resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of co related sub query this can be achieved using join.

this is sample ...

```
 SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN  aa.id is null then null                
                else THEN COALESCE(ub.score*100,0)
               END AS UNUSED
FROM hive_dsn.db.unused_output AS ub
left join hive_dsn.db.access AS aa
on ub.id=aa.id     ;
```

**Note**: If there is 1:n relation ship in tables then use **distinct** in **select** statement.